# Regex working at #regex pork, but not in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the followign Regex:

```
/(?<=SOMEMETHOD\(|\G)\s*((['"]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'"(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|\))/g
```

I tested it on IRC #Regex, and it works.

> !regex 
>   (function() {    new SOMEMETHOD('Parameter
>   1','parameter2',{"json1":0,"json2":14962,"json3":false,"json4":'hej'},lastparameter);
>   morecode(); ests sts st
>   /(?<=SOMEMETHOD(|\G)\s*((['"]).+?(?
>
> [Result: 4] [0:-?: ] [1:90-102: 'Parameter 1'] [2:90-90: ']
>   [3:104-115: 'parameter2'] [4:104-104: '] [5:117-169:
>   {"json1":0,"json2":14962,"json3":false,"json4":'hej'}] [6:171-183:
>   lastparameter]

It dont work in .net though:

```
        string pattern = @"/(?<=SOMEMETHOD\(|\G)\s*((['""]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'""(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|\))/g";

        var t = Regex.Match(e.Document, pattern);
```

I dont know if its an escaping problem of some chars.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work, what specific error are you getting? No matches? Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern shouldn't contain the `/` at the beginning and the `/g` at the end. That is the syntax for declaring a literal regular expression object.

```
string pattern = @"(?<=SOMEMETHOD\(|\G)\s*((['""]).+?(?<!\\)\2|\{[^}]+\}|[^,;'""(){}\)]+)\s*(?:,|\))";
```